# Fetch rows containing 9 digit numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I fetch all the rows that contain 9 digits number from varchar2 columns in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_like()`.

```
SELECT nmuloc
       FROM elbat
       WHERE regexp_like(nmuloc, '[[:digit:]]{9}');
```

The POSIX class `[:digit:]` matches digits (alternatively the range `0-9` can be used). `{9}` is a quantifier requiring the quantified subpattern to occur nine times.

---

Edit:

To match strings, that consist exactly of nine digits:

```
SELECT nmuloc
       FROM elbat
       WHERE regexp_like(nmuloc, '^[[:digit:]]{9}$');
```

`^` matches the beginning and `$` then end of the string.

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit. I guess this would fetch columns that have at least 9 digits.  Is there anything that would fetch columns that have exactly 9 digits?

Comment: @PunterVicky: Add the end of string anchors. See my edit.